# How can I get a list of regex matches for a group?

Tags: regex

I have a group which can occur any number of times in the input string. I need to get a list of all the matching items.

For example, for input:

```
example repeattext 1 anything here repeattext 2 anything repeattext 3
```

My regex is:

```
 (repeattext \d)
```

I want to get the list of matches for the group. Is it possible to use regex here or do I need to parse it myself?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "group", and how is it different from "regex", as you see it? Can you show a complete example, including the language you use, and the code you wrote to match the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use regex here. Your existing regex will do fine.

See http://rubular.com/r/fS8c9C61rG for it in use on your example.

If numbers will ever become 10 or higher, consider this regex:

```
(repeattext \d+)
              ^
              |
              `- matches 1 or more repeating of previous
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
result = subject.scan(/repeattext \d+/)
=> ["repeattext 1", "repeattext 2", "repeattext 3"]
```

See [the docs for the `.scan()` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan).